# Delayed Side Effect in Compose

Tags: android, timer, android-jetpack-compose, side-effects

I have a delayed `LaunchedEffect` that runs every 5 second after the user makes camera to move:

```
public var isMoving: Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)

LaunchedEffect(isMoving) {
    if (!isMoving) {
        delay(5000)
        saveData(data)
    }
}

MyComposeView()
```

This case has a flaw: MyComposeView is recomposing every time the user makes an action. I need to make my `LaunchedEffect` (or any other Side Effect) to use 2 keys: `isMoving` and a timer (instead of current `delay`). I suppose it's possible to make something like a custom state timer like:

```
val timer = remember { mutableStateOf(CustomTimer()) }

LaunchedEffect(isMoving && timer.done) { 
    if (!isMoving) saveData(data)
}
```

where `timer.done` is a repeatable `MutableState`. Is there a simpler way or how it's best to solve the problem?

P.S. if there is another way to skip the recomposition after the `LaunchedEffect` is triggered - it could be even more optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Recomposition occurs when there is a state **read** in Composable's scope. So, if you read the state in a child Composable's scope with the lambda approach and not in the main Composable's scope, you might solve this.

```
@Composable
fun Screen(isMoving: () -> Boolean) {
  // Pass the isMoving reference as parameter
  Timer(
    isMoving = isMoving
    saveData = { saveData(data) }
  )
  MyComposeView()
}

@Composable
fun Timer(
  isMoving: () -> isMoving: Boolean,
  saveData: () -> Unit
) {
  LaunchedEffect(isMoving()) {
    if (!isMoving()) {
      delay(5000)
      saveData(data)
    }
  }
}

// When you're calling the Screen() Composable provide isMoving in the lambda
Screen({ isMoving })
```

This way only the Timer() Composable will get recomposed and will trigger saveData(), there won't be any recompositions in your main Screen()

Comment: `isMoving` is an external variable here. Actually, it's already a `rememberSaveable`,  `cameraPositionState.isMoving`

Comment: you can try to also pass that with lambda approach to root Composable

Comment: Could you update your answer with that?

Comment: Sure, I updated it